# Vectorization of removal of non-periodic offset from data, where offset values are stored in same vector as data

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, vectorization

I have two column matrices with an equal number of rows:

One of the column matrix (let us call it `T`) is a non-periodic set of unique integers sorted in increasing order.      `T` can be simulated by:

```
T=sort(randperm(10E6,100)) ;
T=T';
```

The other column matrix (let us call it `C`) has either 0 or 1 and denotes the status of the corresponding row in `T` in the subsequent operation. 0 is much less likely to occur than 1.  `C` can be simulated by:

```
C=ones(100,1);
C(randperm(100,10))=0;
```

In reality, these column matrices will have several million elements and the examples here are purposefully short to improve the speed of testing.

We step through each row of `C`. If an element in `C` has the value 0 then the corresponding row value in `T` will be subtracted from all subsequent values in each `T` row until we reach another 0 in `C`.

I am now trying to vectorize the following operation to increase the speed when operating on the several million element matrices.

```
lastReset = 0;
newT = NaN*zeros(length(T),1);
for index = 1:length(C)
    if C(index) == 0
        lastReset = T(index);
    else
        newT(index) = T(index) - lastReset;
    end
end
newT(C==0)=[];
```

How could I vectorize the above `for` loop?

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Dear saygins, I'm sorry I haven't included a question. Now I have edited the post specifying my request. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, the key command with "running" operations like this one, is to index an array with the output of `cumsum`:

```
inds = (C == 0);
subT = [0; T(inds)];    
newT = T - subT(cumsum(inds)+1);
newT(inds) = [];
```

But, at least on R2010a (yes, old), it's actually **slower** than your loop for large `N`, and only marginally faster for smaller `N`.

It is much harder to understand, though.